# OpenLayers 2.13 floating components resize not working

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext-2, ext-js-4

In my application i am using ExtJS4. After upgrade from OpenLayers 2.12 to 2.13.1 i noticed that i am unable to resize windows (floating components) that are on top of the map, like the resize action was losing focus. When i drag the window outside map div the resizing works fine. The problem does not exist in 2.12. Also when i set the window to modal, the resize is working properly.

What may be causing such behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my question answered in ol-dev mailing list. Setting fallThrough property to true in openlayers map object did the trick.

More info here: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/notes/2.13.md